# asp.net core proxy/gateway service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm very new with asp.net core and I would ask if my understanding were correct. So, I have some REST APIs - api-1 with url-1, api-2 with url-2 ... api-n with url-n. I need a micro-service which works like a switch, it checks query string and select one from these api-1 to api-n, sends all headers, query string, body to api-* and returns its response.

My understanding is that I need a middleware to do this.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMiddleware<GatewayMiddleware>();
app.Run();
```

and I can do all my staff in `InvokeAsync` like

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var url = GetApiUrlFromQuery(context.Request.QueryString);
        var method = GetHttpMethod(context.Request.Method);

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
        
        // somehow set headers and context
        //request.Headers = context.Request.Headers;
        //request.Content = context.Request.HttpContext;
        
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        // somehow return response
        //context.Response = response;
    }
```

Is it correct or I do something wrong? Which is the best way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The product meet your requirement has already existed,You could check this document:[Implement API Gateways with Ocelot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot)

It record the rerouting information in json file by default,if you want to implement gateway app yourself, you could also consider storing the related information in a configuration file,and here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) related with configration in asp.net core

Answer (score 1):

When you have many microservices you need an API gateway to forward the request to the proper one. I would strongly advice **against** doing this manually, as it is quite complicated. There are many tools that can do this properly and efficiently for you.

### Reverse Proxy/Gateway tools

Here are some projects you can use :

1. [YARP: Yet Another Reverse Proxy](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy)
2. [Ocelot](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot)
3. [Ngnix](https://www.nginx.com) *(not dotnet but useful)*

### Framework solution

Another approach is to use a complete out-of-the-box solution for building microservices, for example using [Phoesion Glow](https://glow.phoesion.com) that i am a developer so i can tell you more information. When you deploy your project in Phoesion Glow it analyzes the assemblies/project to find the proper routing information and applies the changes to it's build-in gateway *(called Prism)*. When the Prism receives a request it figures out the target microservice and forwards it using the service-bus to your service. [Here is the architecture](https://glow-docs.phoesion.com/articles/Architecture_Overview.html)

While Phoesion Glow has it's own SDK for building you business logic *(it's asp-like)* you can also use the ASP.Net framework directly.

[This is an article of how to setup an ASP.Net service in Phoesion Glow](https://glow-docs.phoesion.com/articles/Blog_ASP_and_Glow.html)
and [here is a code sample](https://github.com/Phoesion/Glow-Samples/tree/master/10_AspHosting)

There is also a [playlist with video tutorials showing the basics of creating and deploying a couple of microservices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfrkUuAnT5U&list=PLgd9-Gs1hc3FIME3CIo3yblIbxU5JbTi-) to get you started.

PS : This is the architecture overview
[image: Phoesion Glow Architecture]